# How to search on databases in a hadoop cluster using Solr

Tags: solr, hadoop, spotlight

I currently have a number of databases in a hadoop cluster and wish to index some tables from these databases into a Solr index for searching. Is there a way this can be done? Or is there some mechanism to perform this kind of search in hadoop itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out : http://katta.sourceforge.net/

This is integration of Hadoop / Lucene for distributed index and shards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hadoop itself. However if you are performing various regular expression search, then solr is a very good option. Are you use hive or hbase in hadoop to store your database, or are you storing in flat file?